# Thin Clients that support hardware authentication tokens (Smart Card, NFC etc)

Tags: nfc, smartcards, thin-client

we are looking to overhaul the hardware in use in our warehouse environment. I would like to go for thin clients, with a browser only interface (the only app these clients will be accessing is a web front end, asuthenticated seperately from our Active Directory).

However, we have a real issue with users leaving the existing hardware logged in. so we lose and any all auditing. So, I would like to employe NFC or smart card unlocking/authentication to the TC only (i.e. I am not after using this to pass through to a remote or virtual desktop environment).

Can't see anything via standard searches. Anyone done anything like this or aware of any hardware that supports such a setup?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail to the background to your requirements - as a __ you need to __ so that you can __ , I think there's a bit of context missing :)

Comment: So, we have existing thin clients (HP devices) which boot straight into a web browser and launch the front end for our ERP, which users then log into with their own ERP account. What I want is to secure this with an external authentication device such as NFC or Smart Card. So I am after a tried and tested setup to achieve this. What I want is for users to be able to launch a session simply by tapping the NFC fob on a reader, and for the client to unlock. I am not tied to any specific vendor.